# How to use a deferred result that outputs true or false

Tags: jquery

I'm having a hard time understanding promises and deferreds.

I have a simple function that returns true or false if a user is signed in or not:

```
function checkAuth() {
var IsSignedIn = false;
    $.ajax({
        dataType:"json",
        url: '/utility/SignInStatus', //only returns true if signedin. or else nothing is returned.
        success: function(result) {
           IsSignedIn = (result);
        },
        error: function() {
            alert("you're not logged in");
        }
    });
return (IsSignedIn);
}
```

In another file, I want to use the `checkAuth()` function to see whether the user isSignedIn or not. If checkAuth() returns true then an action can take place. If it returns false, then an action cannot take place.

```
$(document).on('click', 'a[name="deleteaccount"]', function(event) {
  $.when(checkAuth()).done(function(result) {

  // Here is where I want to see if checkAuth() was true or false

   if (!result) {
   // Show alert from the error return from checkAuth()

   } else {
   // Go ahead and delete the account code here

   }

    });)
    };
```

I'm simply not able to get to the `else` part of the statement. How could I achieve this when the `result` is `true`?

Comment: `==` for [comparison](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comparison_Operators). `=` makes an [assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Assignment_Operators).

Comment: You check the result of deferred.resolve (in `done`), yet never set it up. Not sure why do you need it anyway: should `checkAuth` function really be called each time a user clicks a link? Can't you just call it once and store the result in some state variable?

Comment: Because a session can expire in the background (on the server) even though a page may be left open

Comment: @raina77ow can you explain how to get the response from checkAuth() and evaluate whether it was true or false?

Answer (score 1):

The approach below follows your logic to the letter (and answers the given question):

```
function checkAuth() {
    var dfd = $.Deferred();
    $.ajax({
        // ...
        success: function(result) {
           dfd.resolve(true);
        },
        error: function() {
           dfd.resolve(false);
        }
    });
    return dfd.promise();
}
// ...
$(document).on('click', 'a[name="deleteaccount"]', function(event) {
  checkAuth().done(function(result) {
   if (!result) {
     // fail
     return;
   }
   // success
  }); 
});
```

... yet I'd consider different approach: your `$.ajax` call should result in 'success' if and only if a user is authorized, in all the other cases a 403 code (or something similar) will be returned. With this approach, it's possible to go without an additional `Deferred` object, using the one returned by `$.ajax`.

```
function checkAuth() {
  return $.ajax({
    // ...
    error: function() {
      // some common action here - modal, etc.
    }
  });
}

checkAuth().done(function(result) {
  // authorized
}).fail(function(result) {
  // not authorized - do some UC-specific action
});
```

Comment: but I need the error from checkauth() to output an alert when they're not logged in. eventually i want to replace the alert with a modal dialog box asking the user to register/login.

Comment: so just trigger the modal before the `return` after the `//fail`

Comment: @chiliNUT that would mean i have to do that for every single action. there are hundreds of actions that could take place. i'd have to repeat the same code in all of them. its not feasible and doesn't sound like good practice.

Comment: i dont follow, i thought you were just applying this code once in $(document).click

Comment: The reason for the callbacks in checkAuth() was so that every time the user wanted to take an action anywhere on the webpage, it would return an alert/dialog telling them to login. I want this to sit in the checkAuth() function so that I don't have to repeat the code everywhere

Comment: @chiliNUT - no. its being applied on ONE anchor link called deleteaccount. but there are loads more like "like" or "edit" etc etc

Comment: Whoops. Yup. You can trigger the modal before `dtd.resolve(false)`.

Comment: But raina77ow is saying not to have callbacks in CheckAuth(). I'm confused?

Comment: @volumeone But, your original question was how to evaluate the result of check auth and show the alert, so it stands to reason that that is where you would put the alert, so as far as not repeating your code, I still don't know what you mean, you still have to apply the onclick event to whatever links would be affected, so I dont see whats wrong with the modal alert logic being in the onclick event

Comment: Actually, one can combine two approaches: set up some common routines within `$.ajax`, return the promise `$.ajax` itself returns, set up handlers for `.done/.fail` of that promise. Updated the answer (its second part) to show that.